# DKIM record not showing at TXT query

Tags: dkim

I recently implemented DKIM signing for a PHP website containing multiple contact-style web forms and email messages (to avoid my emails being rejected by e.g. GMail).

So I created a DKIM key and added it as a TXT record for the domain. After waiting a few days, I checked the DNS settings using multiple web tools and the "dig" command line tool.

When querying DKIM using the selector (but without the "._domainkey"), it shows the correct DKIM key. However, when executing a regular DNS lookup for TXT records, the DKIM key is still missing, although it was added as TXT.

Now, I'm trying to learn the reason. Does this DNS response mean that the DKIM key is still not applied?